# GDPR and Comunication Preferences

Tags: wordpress

GDPR module has the functionality to send an email to the contact in order to get the Comunication Preferences.
But in my case, I have made a paper document filled and signed by the contact with his comunication preferences. How I could modify the comunication preferences in Civicrm as administrator?

In the Comunication Preferences I don't see any way to update the GDPR status comunication preferences

Answer (score 3):

Communication preferences are stored against contact. You either update each contact by using the communication preferences section on edit or view screen. Or do a bulk update on N contacts using profile.

Cheerz

Pradeep

Comment: In the Comunication Preferences I don't see any way to update the GDPR status comunication preferences.

Comment: on a site we have using GDPR I see a field called GDPR Status in the the Communication Preferences field set on the Contact Summary screen

Comment: I don't see any GDPR field in the Comunication Preferences when edit a contact, I just see it in the summary and GDPR tab in view mode

Answer (score 3):

You could make a table of the data in a spreadsheet and use the Import Wizard to update the preferences.